# PHP foreach loop inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, foreach, checkbox

I am trying to insert the selected values of checkboxes into a mysql database using php. I just can't understand why it's not working because it echoes out all the values fine, but it will only insert the first selected one into the database.

HTML:

```
<b>Injury type:</b>
Bruise <input type='checkbox' name='InjuryType[]' value='1'><br>
Cut <input type='checkbox' name='InjuryType[]' value='2'><br>
Graze <input type='checkbox' name='InjuryType[]' value='3'><br>
Break <input type='checkbox' name='InjuryType[]' value='4'><br>
Bump <input type='checkbox' name='InjuryType[]' value='5'><br>
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['InjuryType'] as $value) {
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO AccidentInjuryLink(InjuryID) VALUES ('$value')");
echo $value; 
}
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` is the data what you expected?

Comment: 1. Don't use the mysql driver, use PDO instead. This prevents SQL injections; I can also see that you're not escaping your posted values.
2. Maybe that column has a primary index which means all numbers must be unique, thus only inserting the first value.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). (Also, like silkfire said, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://goo.gl/SHMN) here, too.)

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) is a brief overview of what they are and how to prevent them.

Comment: are you connected to database?

Comment: If you have an `ID` field make it `auto incremental` and see what happens. Also you should keep error notice on so you can see what errors making the problem

Comment: stop 'spamming' the stop using mysql_*

Comment: @silkfire Thanks, it was to do with the primary index, I changed it and now it works correctly. I know I am open to SQL injection attacks, I'm going to sort that later.

Comment: Accept my answer and make me happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that column has a primary index which means all numbers must be unique, thus only inserting the first value.